# Video composition with Media Foundation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to composite 2 videos into one (audio too) and save as a file. Say, show a source video on the left half of the final video and the ohter source on the right. Any encoding is fine. Not with DirectShow.

I suspected IMFVideoMixerControl may be related to this but unfortunately I'm too new to MF to detemine the right step to take in order to achieve this. If you could give me some guidance or if any example available on the web, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such function in MF. For such a task there is still no alternativ to the (buggy) DirectShow Editing Services! :-(

Comment: At the very minimum, I think I should be able to read the media samples (by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389281(v=vs.85).aspx ), do this with multiple video sources. Composite the byte array frames from the sources into one (Not ideal..). then should be able to write the sample to a IMFSinkWriter to save as a encoded video. I've not tried this yet but it will probably be very slow (Though I don't care too much about perf on my app). So I wonder if there is a better(standard) way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

`IMFVideoMixerControl` is used for rendering video. You're on the right track looking at the SourceReader.

Here's what I would do:

1. Create one `IMFSourceReader` for each video source.
2. Create an `IMFSinkWriter` and configure it with a frame width equal to the sum of the source reader frame widths.

   1. Use `IMFSourceReader::GetCurrentMediaType` to get the source media types.
   2. Use `MFGetAttributeSize` with GUID `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE` to get the frame dimensions for each source type.
   3. Create a media type for the SinkWriter with `MFCreateMediaType` and use `IMFMediaType::CopyAllItems` to copy attributes from the source to sink media types.
   4. Use `MFSetAttributeSize` with GUID `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE` to set the sink type's increased frame dimensions.
   5. Use `IMFSinkWriter::AddStream` to create a video stream identical to the source type, except for the width attribute
3. Call IMFSourceReader::ReadSample for each source, giving you one IMFSample for each source.
4. Allocate a new `IMFSample`, attaching a new `IMFMediaBuffer` with the increased frame width.
5. Use `MFCopyImage` to copy each of the source buffers to the corresponding side of the allocated media buffer.
6. Use `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` to write your `IMFSample` to the file sink.

See [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some basic SourceReader/SinkWriter processing, although this example uses a video capture source instead of a file. You can create a file SourceReader using `MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL` instead of `MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource`.

Edit: I realized that you asked about audio, too. My answer only addresses compositing the video streams.